# Validate form so End Date can not be before Start Date. - PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, date

I have this part of a form where it shows end start and end date. I have validated it so that if no date is entered then an error message will show asking the use to enter a date, however, I need it to also check that the end date is not before the start date and echo an error asking the user to make sure the end date is after the start date if this happens. It's probably something very simple but I just can't figure out the correct code. Thanks.

```
// event start date
echo "<li class='cf'>";
echo "<label for='startdate'>Start date</label>";
echo "<div class='input'>";
echo "<input name='startdate' class='eventdate' placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY' type='date' value='";
if (!is_null($postedData['startdate'])) { echo $postedData['startdate']; };
echo "' />";
if($failedData['startdate']) { echo "<p class='error'>Please enter the date of your event.</p>";    }   
echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";

echo $postedData['startdate'];

// event end date
echo "<li class='cf'>";
echo "<label for='enddate'>End date</label>";
echo "<div class='input'>";
echo "<input name='enddate' class='eventdate' placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY' type='date' value='";
if (!is_null($postedData['date'])) { echo $postedData['date']; };
echo "' />";
if($failedData['enddate']) { echo "<p class='error'>Please enter the date of your event.</p>"; }    

echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";

echo $postedData['enddate'];

echo "<li class='cf'>";
echo "<label for='timestart'>Event time</label>";
echo "<div class='input inputs'>";
```

Comment: Why are you putting all the validations on server side. Is there a reason before submitting the page you can not validate it on client side ? Also the way you are generating HTML out of echo statements is not good.

Comment: This is the code I was given to work with, I can't change it too much, therefore I am just looking for a solution to my question but I appreciate your input.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq You should ALWAYS validate user input server sided as well!! And yes, you are right that he should not be echoing html statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a simple idea

```
$a = "2014-01-01";
$b = "2014-02-01";
$date1 = strtotime($a);
$date2 = strtotime($b);

if($date1 > $date2){
  // Date one is >
}
else{
  // Date 2 is >
}
```

Date can be formatted in php